# Issue with xlsx.full.min.js Stopped working since April 27th

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I have an LWC component based out of https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/ExcelUpload and this stopped working in Prod Org starting Apr 26 2022. This is however working fine in my sandboxes. I get the below error.

In the developer console I get this error, this has the window.XLSX fix in it and the same code works in sandbox as well

Error: Error loading SheetJS library (XLSX undefined)
at eval (./locker/c/excelToJsonStatic.js:16:17)
at eval (eval at createConnector (aura_proddebug.js:21015:12), :1365:19)
at foreignErrorControlFn (aura_proddebug.js:19577:20)
at BoundaryProxyHandler.applyTrap [as apply] (aura_proddebug.js:20130:34)

I did raise a support ticket but the response is slow to my liking so wanted to see if I could get help here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve to issue by turning "Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components" OFF
This for reason got turned on for some reason.

[image]

Comment: We've [been told](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lws_enabling_begins.htm&type=5&release=236) this feature would start being enabled in February 2022, and that administrators would be notified in advance by email. In other words, it's recommended that you check your email regularly, and read the release notes periodically.

Comment: That said, if something is working in LS (Locker Service), but **not** working in LWS, you need to bring up a case with support, or contact salesforce.com through the [Lightning Components Development](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F930000000PbJaCAK?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC) group. Odds are, if you're having a problem, other people will, too. You should build a reproduction of the issue that you can share so that we can help get this resolved. **Igoring** this issue isn't an option, as it will eventually be forced in all orgs.

Comment: I second what @sfdcfox said - LWS is the new model and Locker is going away so in a few months that checkbox will be checked and disabled for you.

Comment: Agree, I am already working with support team, two things, this settings is supposed to be enabled in all org where there are only LWC components but mine has aura as well, so it shouldn’t have been enabled without my consent.
Also LWC should work with LWS seemlessly from what I read  it isn’t in this case, but as you said I had to find the right solution no matter what.